# Question About An Induction Problem: What Am I Supposed To Prove?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I've encountered this induction problem, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to prove. I would like an explanation on a few things about the problem; **I'm not looking for a hint/solution to the problem**. The problem here is: 
[image]

What I'm confused about is the following:

1. What is "cap"/hemisphere? Right now, I'm imagining something that looks like this:

[image]

2. What does choosing a hemisphere mean? And what does removing a hemisphere mean? Right now, I'm imagining something that looks like this:

[image]

3. What does "keeping the sphere covered mean"? Right now, I think it means that as long as the sphere has caps on it, it's "covered". But then I doubt this is correct, because the problem would be trivial- since I've chosen 4 caps to remain, it's covered. So I'm wondering what the right interpretation of this is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the important part here is that the hemispheres don't actually stick out of the sphere; they're hemispheres of the *actual sphere* itself.

Here's a better way to phrase the question: A *cap* is a hemisphere of the *sphere*, and we have some set of caps such that their union is the whole sphere. Prove that there is a subset of four caps whose union is still the whole sphere.

Comment: So I'm supposed to prove it's possible to choose 4 hemispheres such that even if I remove everything else, I can still form a sphere with those 4 hemispheres?

Comment: Yes, you want to find 4 hemispheres which cover the whole sphere by themselves.

Comment: Sorry, what does cover the whole sphere by themselves mean?

Comment: It means that the union of the four hemispheres is the sphere. The radius of the hemisphere is the same as that of the sphere; each one fits perfectly to cover half.

Comment: Final question, must a hemisphere be a half sphere, or can it just be any cut of the sphere? I searched up what a hemisphere is, and it says the former is true, but the latter would make more sense.

Comment: A hemisphere means exactly half a sphere.

Comment: But then how can you have 4 hemispheres? You can only cut a sphere into 2 halves.

Comment: The hemispheres are allowed to overlap.

Comment: I'm sorry, now I'm confused about what removing a hemisphere means. If hemispheres overlap, and we remove all but 4 hemispheres, what does that mean?

Comment: Consider any hemisphere. We have some set of hemispheres, which can overlap, the hemispheres cover the whole sphere. Then we simply want to show that we can pick 4 hemispheres from our set which still cover the whole sphere.

Comment: Ah, so what we're supposed to show is: let's say we start with the set of all possible hemispheres, and remove all but 4 of them. Show that it's possible for the 4 of them to encompass the entire sphere. Is that right?

Comment: Almost right; we're not starting with the set of all possible hemispheres, but rather some finite set of hemispheres which can be used to encompass the entire sphere; we want to find 4 of them which do the same thing.

Comment: So we need to show this is true for any set of hemispheres, as long as that set of hemispheres covers the entire sphere?